# Possible to retrieve Google Cloud Messaging registration ids?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I is possible to see, which devices has registred to GCM while using my application which has a GCM registration. I know, I can save them into a mysql - but is there any other way to see ALL ids registred?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410469/how-to-get-the-list-of-devices-which-are-registered-in-google-cloud-messaging-se

Answer (score 0):

No, the only way to get all IDs registered is to fetch them from your server's DB, which means you have to maintain that list youself.